# Can't make bibliography with TexShop

Tags: bibliographies, texshop

I'm using TexShop for my thesis and can't cite the article.
When I run the command to generate the bibliography, I have "?" in my PDF where I wrote my citation.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I don't know the degree of automation in TeXShop, but usually you have to run LaTeX at least once, then bibtex or biber to generate the bibliographic data, and then LaTeX again (usually two times). Please provide more details about which steps you did (including editing the bib file), and check the log for any errors or information.

Comment: I do know the degree of automation in TeXShop.  gernot is correct.  You can also try changing the Typeset option to `pdflatexmk`.  Please let us know how this turns out.

Comment: When did you last update your TeX distribution (MacTeX?).

Comment: When you say "run for bibliography" (which is being edited to say "run the command to generate the bibliography"), what do you mean by that?